# php function disk_free_space path in subdomain

Tags: php

i have host - sub domain with Separate server . like :

```
site.com
doc.site.com (on new server)
```

disk_free_space work on main server Correct with this path :

```
disk_free_space("/");
disk_total_space("/");
```

but on sub domain all path not work and function return zero . what path is correct for my position?

```
disk_free_space("subdomain path?");
disk_total_space("subdomain path?");
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHP manual clearly states the following for the [`total_disk_space`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-total-space.php) method:

> Given a string containing a directory, this function will return the total number of bytes on the corresponding filesystem or disk partition.

If your subdomain is on a different partition, I would say you can use `disk_total_space` and `disk_free_space` methods.

Keep in mind that the return value is either the total number of bytes as a float or `false` on failure, so you might as well check that with the [`is_float`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) method:

```
$totalDiskSpace = disk_total_space("/");

if(is_float($totalDiskspace))
{
    //
    // Do something with $totalDiskSpace.
    //
}
else
{
    //
    // Throw an exception or show an error.
    //
}
```

Comment: function return only 0 and nothing

Comment: What does a `var_dump` give as type? Float, int or null?

Comment: What is the difference between the operating system and web server at the *main server* and  the sub domain server? It seems unexpected that `disk_free_space` returns `null`. I know that different operating system and web server combinations sometime create issues.

Comment: no both os is same . apache on linux and php5.5 on directadmin

Answer (score 0):

This can happen with problems with permissions.  Suppose you want:

```
disk_free_space("/a/b/c/d");
```

The directory **c** needs rx permissions for the user running php.  As test doing a:

```
chmod go+rx /a/b/c
```

should allow the disk_free_space to work properly.

Curiously (at least on Centos 7) it is the directory containing the directory or mount-point being queried that needs these permissions, rather than the directory /a/b/c/d itself.